# How to use alias inside another alias in ZSH?

Tags: bash, zsh, bash-alias

Let's say I have the following alias definition in my ZSH config file:

```
alias myalias="cd /"
```

how can I use `myalias` inside another alias? ie:

```
alias myaliasone="myalias && cd /usr"
```

I have tried (with a real alias this one is a fake just for example purposes) but nothing happens and I am not able to see any errors as per debug or fix something, any ideas? If this is the right way to use alias inside another alias, do you know how I can debug this so I can find the root problem or what is happening?

Comment: You need to use functions. See [alias - Resolve all aliases in a zsh command line - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150649/resolve-all-aliases-in-a-zsh-command-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

#### Use a function instead of an alias

```bash
myalias() {
  cd /
}
alias myaliasone='myalias && cd /usr'
```

#### Use the `$aliases` table

```bash
zmodload -F zsh/parameter p:aliases
alias myalias='cd /'
alias myaliasone='$aliases[myalias] && cd /usr'
```

Note that the string needs to be in `'`single quotes`'`, to prevent `$`parameters inside it from being substituted immediately. Now they will be substituted when the command line is being evaluated, *after* aliases are substituted.

Comment: I know this is a bit dated now but ... how do you call others aliases inside your alias function? Let's say you have the `docker-compose` plugin enabled and I want to call `dcup` inside my alias... I did it as (this goes inside my function) `cd /usr || exit && dcup` but it does not execute the 2nd command in the chain meaning `dcup` never gets executed

Comment: @ReynierPM If `cd /usr` succeeds (returns 0), then whatever is to the right of `||` won’t be evaluated. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines